# Sharepoint - Add Blog site lists to a new site definition

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am creating a new site definition. This will have three sections, Document library, Discussion group and Blogs.

I can create the easily by using Blog site template. But we want this to be extensible as we are using this by mating with a product of us. The sites will be created dynamically.

Now, I am looking for ways to extract Blog site lists like Posts, Comments and Categories in to my site definition or in to a new feature.

I tried to save a blog site as template and open the template file in VS 2010. But that contains lot of files and i have no idea what files to copy in to my solution.

I am fairly new to SharePoint development. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to open up the onet.xml from 14Hive\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\Blog\Xml and see how the various list instances are created there, and put them into the onet.xml for your site def.

Comment: Lists present in the blog site are part of the site template. They are not implemented as list templates or features. So, i also need to make forms, list instances etc as part of my site. I am not sure what files need to be imported in to Visual Studio.